# Driving 8 x 117W COB LEDs

Tags: dc-dc-converter, led-driver, constant-current, cob

I am currently attempting to design a LED grow light using the following LEDs but I am having a very hard time finding a sufficient power supply.

8 x Lumileds - SunPlus CoBs
[DataSheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/602/DS195-1371856.pdf)
51.7 V, 2250mA

The first complication is that these lights will be powered by a 380VDC system, not your typical 110-220VAC Power.  So I believe that I am looking for a DC/DC CC Driver for each CoB?  I would also like to run these 8 CoBs in a parallel configuration, this way if one LED dies the rest will still function.

I know 380VDC sounds odd but if interested in why that is a requirement here is a great article:
https://www.led-professional.com/resources-1/articles/direct-current-dc-supply-grids-for-led-lighting

Also just for reference here is the link to the External power supplies that will be providing that 380VDC power:
https://www.artesyn.com/power/documents/606/

1: At what current should I run these CoB LEDs? I am assuming that running at max current of 2250mA would destroy the lifetime of the LED as well as produce an insane amount of heat?

2: Does anybody have any suggestions on a dc-dc CC Driver for these CoBs? I would prefer not to have to design my own LED driver but will if absolutely necessary.  Ideally I would like to use a pre-built Driver like MeanWell, Glacial Power, Artesyn, etc, but I cannot find one that, A: V-in is 380VDC and B: Is a CC Driver capable of ~2A output W/ PWM or Analog dimming control.  There are just so many brands out there and I do not want to use anything unreliable, hence why I am reaching out for help!

Anyway Thank you all! Looking forward to your responses!

Comment: Why are you set on 350VDC specifically?  Your linked article talks about advantages of DC grids generally, and uses an example of 380V as a reasonable choice in general, but when you have a specific device you're trying to power, you would do better to choose a power supply more appropriate to it.

Comment: Also, are you planning on distributing that 350VDC over long distances?  Because if not, that solution will almost certainly be less efficient than scrapping the 350VDC power supply and just distributing the AC you already have.

Comment: @NateStrickland First of all thank you for pointing out the 350VDC, I got that mixed up and met to put 380VDC, I have made edits to original post.  Second, yes this 380VDC will be distributed over a 2000sq/ft warehouse and the goal is to be able to run multiple of these lighting fixtures in a parallel configuration across the warehouse.

Comment: To clarify, the 380VDC system is already installed/running in the warehouse, and/or you have other uses for 380VDC in that warehouse?  Because otherwise those power supplies you linked look like a whole lot of overkill for your intended use.  You might gain a few percent efficiency in distribution, but for such a low load, you'll burn up more power doing an extra conversion step.

Comment: @NateStrickland Yes, This is a commercial horticulture application,so the load will be very large, aka lots of these lighting fixtures in the distributed 380VDC system.

Comment: @NateStrickland 380 VDC is currently being pushed for datacenter use, it's been shown to be more efficient than 240 VAC and especially -48 VDC for the switched computer loads. If his density is approaching datacenter, I believe when he says it's better.

Comment: That's fair.  I was asking mainly because the OP said only 8 LEDs at 2.2A each, which would be easy to efficiently power from 240VAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouser's search for LED drivers lets you specify an input voltage range, output voltage range, output current ability, and constant-current operation.  Here's that search with your parameters entered: [CC LED Drivers](https://www.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/LED-Lighting/LED-Lighting-Electronics/LED-Drivers-Power-Supplies/_/N-b1asl?P=1yzneyeZ1yzneymZ1yzvclyZ1yzvclrZ1ya6wfoZ1yxe5iqZ1yvvbyeZ1ysxhfsZ1y9ksr1Z1yp07glZ1yvm6r8Z1yzney1Z1yyo235Z1y9kpvcZ1yzot00Z1yvvbycZ1y92d4uZ1y92d4vZ1y92d4tZ1y92d6aZ1y92d4wZ1y92d3cZ1yxt5gxZ1y92d5cZ1y92d38Z1y92d67Z1y92d43Z1y9179lZ1y92d76Z1y92d31Z1y92d9qZ1y92czyZ1y92d44Z1y92d24Z1y92d54Z1y92d68Z1y92d4nZ1y92d45Z1y92d21Z1y92d29Z1y92d30Z1y92d0zZ1yxt77oZ1yurf37Z1yurf34Z1yxt77mZ1yxt73e)

This device looks like it might be a perfect fit: [MEAN-WELL_NPF-120D-54BE](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/NPF-120D-54BE?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvV8Y9YugmIggKrro5yrY7wk0uepjdY9x9UvWrqBHc7Nw%3d%3d)

It accepts 127-431VDC input, and supplies up to 2300mA at 32-54VDC, and is dimmable.  You'd need one per LED, which should be doable as they're only $46 each.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for what current I should run the CoBs at? Should I push full 2250mA through each LED or a lower current in order to extend the life / thermal properties of the LED?

Also I dont know how I missed this driver but this looks perfect thank you!

Comment: Given that the datasheet lists the 2250mA as "test current" for the rest of their specs (as opposed to "absolute max" and a lower "typical" current rating) I would think that it'd be fine to run them at that current for extended periods, provided you have proper heatsinking.